# Sybase: how to check case-sensitivity

Tags: sybase

In my Java application, it needs to find out whether the underlying Sybase db is case-sensitive or case-insensitive at server start-up and config the property accordingly, is there any proper ways to do that?

Answer (score 2):

If `select if 'A' = 'a' then 0 else 1 endif` returns 1, then the DB is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Case sensitivity is indicated by the Character Set & Sort Order of the server.

You can pull the sort order, and character set from master..syscurconfigs

```
select value from master..syscurconfigs where config = 132  #Gives you Sort Order ID
select value from master..syscurconfigs where config =      #Gives you Character Set ID
```

Once you have the two values, you can pull the name of the sort order:

```
select name from master..syscharsets where id = SortOrderID and csid = CharSetID
```

If the name includes `nocase` (for English sets), or `nocs` (non-English sets) then it is case insensitive.

**I know I am missing a value in my second query, but I will fill it in when I get back to my notes tomorrow*

Comment: Well, stack is not letting me edit my answer, but I typo'd the Sort Order config..it should be 123, and the Charset ID is 131.  I'll fix my answer later at a different computer.